# Looping through a nested JavaScript object

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm using Angular 5 in my project, I want to loop through a JavaScript object that looks like this:

```
var items = [
    {
        "departure": "new york",
        "arrival": "new jersy",
        "stations": [
            { "station": "new_1" },
            { "station": "new_2" },
            { "station": "new_3" },
            // ...
        ]
    }
];
```

here's the code:

```
generateStationPriceMethode(items: any) {
    if (items.stations.length > 0) {
        let user = {
            "stationPrice": "00",
            "stationName": items.departure + "-" + items.stations[0].station,
        };

        this.setItem<priceStation>(this.myObject, (u) => u.station == station, user);
        for (let i = 0; i < items.stations.length; i++) {
            alert('eee');
            let user = {
                "stationPrice": "00",
                "stationName": items.stations[i].station + "-" + items.stations[i + 1].station,
            };
            this.setItem<priceStation>(this.myObject, (u) => u.station == station, user);
        }

    } else if (!items.stations.length) {
        let user = {
            "stationPrice": "00",
            "stationName": items.departure + "-" + items.arrival,
        };

        this.setItem<priceStation>(this.myObject, (u) => u.station == station, user);
    }

    console.log("youssef :" + JSON.stringify(this.obj.StationPrice));
}
```

another function:

```
setItem<T>(array: Array < T >, predicate: Predicate < T >, item: T) {
    var _oldItem = _.find(array, predicate);
    if (_oldItem) {
        var index = _.indexOf(array, _oldItem);
        array.splice(index, 1, item);
    } else {
        array.push(item);
    }
}
```

when `generateStationPriceMethode` executes, it throws this error:

> ERROR ReferenceError: station is not defined

What I want to get from `generateStationPriceMethode` is this object:

```
var myObject = [
    { "stationPrice": "00", "stationName": "new york - new_1"},
    { "stationPrice": "00", "stationName": "new_1 - new_2" },
    { "stationPrice": "00", "stationName": "new_2 - new_3" },
    { "stationPrice": "00", "stationName": "new york - new jersy" },
];
```

When `items.stations.length < 0` (I mean stations object does not exist) I want to get this object instead:

```
var myObject = [
    {
        "stationPrice": "00",
        "stationName":"new york - new jersy",
    },
];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `reduce` function.

## Look at this code snippet.

```js
var items = [{
  "departure": "new york",
  "arrival": "new jersy",
  "stations": [
    {"station": "new_1"}, 
    {"station": "new_2"},
    {"station": "new_3"}
  ]
}];

var getStations = function() {
  var stations = [];
  items.forEach((sts) => {
    if (sts.stations === undefined || sts.stations.length === 0)  {
      stations.push({
        "stationPrice": "00",
        "stationName": `${sts.departure} - ${sts.arrival}`
      });

      return false;
    }

    stations = [...[sts.departure], ...sts.stations.map((s) => s.station)].reduce((a, c, i, arr) => {
      if (i + 1 === arr.length) {
        a.push({
          "stationPrice": "00",
          "stationName": `${arr[i]} - ${sts.arrival}`
        });

        return a;
      };

      a.push({
        "stationPrice": "00",
        "stationName": `${c} - ${arr[i + 1]}`
      });

      return a;
    }, []);

    stations.push({
      "stationPrice": "00",
      "stationName": `${sts.departure} - ${sts.arrival}`
    });

  });

  return stations;
};

console.log(getStations(items));

items = [{
  "departure": "new york",
  "arrival": "new jersy",
  "stations": []
}];

console.log('------- Stations = []');
console.log(getStations(items));

items = [{
  "departure": "new york",
  "arrival": "new jersy"
}];
console.log('------- Stations = undefined');
console.log(getStations(items));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important
}
```

```html
myObject=[{"stationPrice": "00", "stationName":"new york - new_1"},{"stationPrice": "00", "stationName":"new_1 - new_2"}, {"stationPrice": "00", "stationName":"new_2 - new_3"},....,{"stationPrice": "00", "stationName":"new york - new jersy"}]
```

## Resource

[`Array.prototype.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

## UPDATE

**What does the code below**

```
[...[sts.departure], ...sts.stations.map((s) => s.station)]
```

First you need to read a little about [`Spread operator`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator).

**That line returns the following:**

```
["new york", "new_1", "new_2", "new_3"]
```

Comment: thnaks ser, but it doesnt work as expected , image i have, var items = [{
  "departure": "new york",
  "arrival": "new jersy",
  "stations": [
    {"station": "new_1"}
  
  ]
}]; your code prints :[{"stationPrice":"00","stationName":"new york - new_1"},{"stationPrice":"00","stationName":"new york - new jersy"}] and this is not the right result

Comment: your code should print "stationName":"new _3 - new jersy"} also

Comment: i'm sorry i didnt mentioned that in the code above, but can you please edit code for the case :{"stationName":"new _3 - new jersy"}

Comment: @yoyo1236areezd I don't understand.  The output follows what you've stated in your question.  can you share once again your desired output.  Further, this answer has three output following three scenarios: 1- stations.length > 0, stations.length = 0 and stations = undefined.

Comment: @yoyo1236areezd I've updated the answer, can you check once again?

Comment: myObject=[{"stationPrice": "00", "stationName":"new york - new_1"},{"stationPrice": "00", "stationName":"new_1 - new_2"}, {"stationPrice": "00", "stationName":"new_2 - new_3"}, {"stationPrice": "00", "stationName":"new_3 - new jersy"},{"stationPrice": "00", "stationName":"new york - new jersy"}]

Comment: @yoyo1236areezd are you sure you want this `{"stationPrice": "00", "stationName":"new york - new jersy"}` as the last item in your output?

Comment: ,{"stationPrice": "00", "stationName":"new york - new jersy"} has disapeared

Comment: thank you ser, areezd did a good work too, thank you very mutch

Comment: could you explain the line of code please : stations = [...[sts.departure], ...sts.stations.map((s) => s.station)].reduce((a, c, i, arr) => {
      if (i + 1 === arr.length) {

Comment: @yoyo1236areezd see the updated answer.  I've put a little explanation.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's a good idea to flat you array.
Are you sure you don't want an array of possible routes? Or are you sure you will only have 1 item ?

But you can do something like this:

```js
var items=[{"departure":"new york","arrival":"new jersy","stations":[{"station":"new_1"},{"station":"new_2"},{"station":"new_3"}]}];
var result = items.reduce((acumulator, item) => {
 let previousStation;
 const stations = item.stations.map((station) => {
   const first = previousStation ? previousStation.station :  item.departure;
    previousStation = station;
    return {
     stationPrice: '00',
      stationName: `${first} - ${station.station}` 
    };
  });
  stations.push(...[{
   stationPrice: '00',
    stationName: `${previousStation.station} - ${item.arrival}`
  }, {
    stationPrice: '00',
    stationName: `${item.departure} - ${item.arrival}`
  }])
  acumulator.push(...stations);
  return acumulator;
}, []);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: I add console.log() it works good for me. What do say by "it doesn't work" ?

Comment: @yoyo1236areezd Click on "Run code snippet" you will see the result.

Comment: its not the same as myObject=[{"stationPrice": "00", "stationName":"new york - new_1"},{"stationPrice": "00", "stationName":"new_1 - new_2"}, {"stationPrice": "00", "stationName":"new_2 - new_3"}, {"stationPrice": "00", "stationName":"new_3 - new jersy"},{"stationPrice": "00", "stationName":"new york - new jersy"}]

Comment: , {"stationPrice": "00", "stationName":"new_3 - new jersy"} is absent

Comment: thank you very much for your help, you and @Ele did a great work.

Comment: i hope you fix the problem you have so that i can do a benchmark of the two solution

Comment: I just added {
    stationPrice: '00',
    stationName: `${item.departure} - ${item.arrival}`
  }
because I seen you need "new york - new jersy". You can remove it if you don't want it anymore.
Enjoy.